# Add row if len(row) == 2 (python, csv)

Tags: python, csv, row

I would like to generate a new row when there are only 2 rows

```
with open(pathCSV) as f:
     reader = csv.reader(f)
     for row in reader:                     
         if len(row) == 2:
            #add row
```

if i print my row it return me that:

```
['Contrôle', '']
['CLÉS', '']
['Entrée', '4 clés entrées']
['Entrée 2', '1 clé entrée porte bâtiment']
```

and i want to have:

```
['Contrôle', '','']
['CLÉS', '','']
['Entrée', '4 clés entrées','']
['Entrée 2', '1 clé entrée porte bâtiment','']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just appending a new value should work.

```
with open(pathCSV) as f:
     reader = csv.reader(f)
     for row in reader:                     
         if len(row) == 2:
             row.append('')
             print(row)
```

returns

```
['Contrôle', '','']
['CLÉS', '','']
['Entrée', '4 clés entrées','']
['Entrée 2', '1 clé entrée porte bâtiment','']
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems so obvious now!

Comment: if that works, please be sure to mark the question as closed.